# Does "not mean independent" imply "not independent"?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation, independence

If X and Y are two random variables such that $E(X | Y = y) \neq E (X)$ for some $y \in D_y$, then X is not mean independent from Y. Does it imply that X and Y are also not stochastically independent?

Comment: The premise of your question doesn’t make sense as conditional expectation is only defined almost surely

Comment: I would have assumed the question would be in the other direction: "Give an example of $X,Y$ that are not independent, but $E[X|Y=y]=E[X]$ for all possible $y$."  For the question you asked, you want to assume $X,Y$ are independent and then prove $E[X|Y=y]=E[X]$. Perhaps you can take the case when $(X,Y)$ is discrete, so $E[X|Y=y]= \sum_{x \in S_X} x P[X=x|Y=y]$ for all $y \in S_Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, because it is the contrapositive version of the Theorem stating that *independence* $\Rightarrow$ *mean independence*: Let $X, Y_1, Y_2$ be random variables, if $(X, Y_1)$ is independent of $Y_2$, then
$$
E[X|Y_1, Y_2] = E[X| Y_1]  \quad a.s.,
$$
(while the opposite direction is not true, see counterexample of @Peter Strouvelle).

Contraposition: Not-mean-independence $\Rightarrow$ not-independence.

Comment: Now I understand it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The standard counterexample is the following. Let $U\sim \mathcal U_{(0,2\pi]}$, and define the vector $(X,Y):=(\cos(U),\sin(U))$. Then $X^2+Y^2=1$, and thus $X=\pm\sqrt{1-Y^2}$. Therefore, for $Y(\omega)=y$, $X$ is uniform distributed on $\{-\sqrt{1-y^2},\sqrt{1-y^2}\}$.
Thus, $\mathbb E(X|Y=y)=0$ for all $y$. You can easily check, that $X$ and $Y$ can not be independent. Thus mean independence does not imply independence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was already aware that mean independence did not imply stochastic independence. My question was if variables that are not mean independent were also always not independent.

Comment: Double negative got me confused.